# Postgresql change data dir and socket error

Tags: server, apt, postgresql

When I chenge postgresql data directory in

> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

form default path

> /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main

to my custom

> /home/user/postgresql/9.5/main

Use this manual https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have error:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

When I wrong?

**UPD1**

```
ubuntu@rails-serv-1:~$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2016-10-19 08:52:12 UTC; 4min 52s ago
Process: 854 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 854 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 0
Memory: 0B
CPU: 0
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Oct 19 08:52:12 rails-serv-1 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Oct 19 08:52:12 rails-serv-1 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

**UPD2**

```
ubuntu@rails-serv-1:~$ sudo ps auxww | grep [p]ostgresql
ubuntu@rails-serv-1:~$
```

is empty

```
ubuntu@rails-serv-1:~$  sudo ls -al /var/run/postgresql
total 0
drwxrwsr-x  2 postgres postgres  40 Oct 19 21:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root     root     900 Oct 19 21:32 ..
```

**UPD3**

log

```
"2016-10-21 07:25:54 UTC [3493-1] FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql-new/9.5/main" has group or world access 2016-10-21 07:25:54 UTC [3493-2] DETAIL: Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)."
```

folders permissions

```
root@rails-serv-1:~# cd /var/lib/postgresql-new/
root@rails-serv-1:/var/lib/postgresql-new# ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 9.5
root@rails-serv-1:/var/lib/postgresql-new# cd 9.5/
root@rails-serv-1:/var/lib/postgresql-new/9.5# ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:01 main
root@rails-serv-1:/var/lib/postgresql-new/9.5# cd main/
root@rails-serv-1:/var/lib/postgresql-new/9.5/main# ls -lh
total 80K
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 base
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:01 global
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_clog
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_commit_ts
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_dynshmem
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_logical
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_multixact
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_notify
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_replslot
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_serial
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:01 pg_stat
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_twophase
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    4 Oct 18 23:00 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4.0K Oct 18 23:00 pg_xlog
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   88 Oct 18 23:00 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  133 Oct 18 23:00 postmaster.opts
```

Comment: Did you restart the postgresql server?  Can you see it in the ps output?

Comment: Yes postgresql servis is run. Add listing in text

Comment: Does the output of ps auxww | grep [p]ostgresql  show the new data directory after the "-D" and the config file you edited after the "-c"?  Does the socket file exist and owned by postgresql? ( sudo ls -al /var/run/postgresql )

Comment: add listing  in UPD2

Comment: postgreaql is not running, the ps output should look something like: postgres  1131  0.0  0.1 301728 24264 ?        S    Oct14   0:04 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
Look for problems in the log files in /var/log/postgresql

Comment: in log i have `"2016-10-21 07:25:54 UTC [3493-1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql-new/9.5/main" has group or world access
2016-10-21 07:25:54 UTC [3493-2] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)."`.I think problem in shared folder and vagrant configuration. Ubuntu is virtual mashine, and new postgresql dir is shared folder.

Comment: @alexin i have the same exact set-up Ubuntu on virtual machine and psql on shared folder. Followed the same article and have the same output. Did you find a solution?